# How to select an element in svg in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an application in D3 which forms a network like structure,it has a few nodes thats are connected to each other.Now i want to select a portion of that network and also want the values of that selected portion.here i am posting my screen shot[image: this is the network i created using D3]

[image: i want this type of selection]

Now i want to select Foxconn and Amazon nodes and also want their values..

here is my code in D3..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.link {
fill: none;
stroke: #666;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#licensing {
fill: green;
} 

.link.licensing {
stroke: green;
}

.link.resolved {
stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1;
}

circle {
fill: #ccc;
stroke: #333;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
font: 10px sans-serif;
pointer-events: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<script>
    // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/

    /*Here licensing type is making the green arrow
     *Here resolved type is making the solid arrow
     *Here suit type is making the dotted arrow
     *
     *
     **/

    var links = [ {
        source : "Microsoft",
        target : "Amazon",
        type : "licensing"
    }, {
        source : "Microsoft",
        target : "HTC",
        type : "licensing"
    }, {
        source : "Samsung",
        target : "Apple",
        type : "suit"
    }, {
        source : "Motorola",
        target : "Apple",
        type : "suit"
    }, {
        source : "Nokia",
        target : "Apple",
        type : "resolved"
    }, {
        source : "HTC",
        target : "Apple",
        type : "suit"
    }, {
        source : "Kodak",
        target : "Apple",
        type : "suit"
    }, {
        source : "Kodak",
        target : "Qualcomm",
        type : "licensing"
    } ];

    var nodes = {};

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
            name : link.source
        });
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
            name : link.target
        });
    });

    var width = 960, height = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(d3.values(nodes)).links(links)
            .size([ width, height ]).linkDistance(60).charge(-300).on(
                    "tick", tick).start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
            "height", height);

    var gStates = svg.selectAll("g.state").data(links);

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", function(d, i) {
        var selection = d3.selectAll('.selected');

        if (selection[0].indexOf(this) == -1) {
            selection.classed("selected", false);
            selection = d3.select(this);
            selection.classed("selected", true);
        }

        selection.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            d.x += d3.event.dx;
            d.y += d3.event.dy;
            return "translate(" + [ d.x, d.y ] + ")"
        })
        // reappend dragged element as last
        // so that its stays on top
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    });


    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker").data(
            [ "suit", "licensing", "resolved" ]).enter().append("marker")
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d;
            }).attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10").attr("refX", 15).attr("refY",
                    -1.5).attr("markerWidth", 6).attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto").append("path").attr("d",
                    "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path").data(force.links())
            .enter().append("path").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "link " + d.type;
            }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
            });

    var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle").data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("circle").attr("r", 6).call(force.drag);

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text").data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("text").attr("x", 8).attr("y", ".31em").text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    });

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
        path.attr("d", linkArc);
        circle.attr("transform", transform);
        text.attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function linkArc(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, dy = d.target.y - d.source.y, dr = Math
                .sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr
                + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff thanks for your i am able to get all elements in the console but now i need that i will select more than one node and those nodes will go to console.can you help plese ??this is the only issue i have stucked with..please please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter a selection with [`.filter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter). In your case, this would look something like this.

```
var selected = circle.filter(function(d) {
         return d.name == "Amazon" || d.name == "Foxconn";
});
```

Now you can operate on that selection, where `this` will be the `circle` elements and the data is accessible in the usual way.

```
selected.each(function(d) {
  // d contains the data for the node and this is the circle element
});
```

Comment: i have edited my codes with yours but the problem is that i want to select more than one node and it may be any nodes and i  want to select them together.

Comment: Yes, that's what `.filter()` is for. You can specify arbitrary code that defines the selection.

Answer (score 1):

when you use enter() to append node, i think you should add some attribute to label the

node such as a id

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template Index</title>
</head>
<body>

  <ul id="comp">
  </ul>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var company = [
    { id: "IBM", value: "222"},
    { id: "MS", value: "222"},
    { id: "Google", value: "222"}
  ];
  var comp = d3.select("#comp").selectAll(".com")
    .data(company)
    .enter()
    .append("li")
    .attr("id", function (d) { return "id" + d.id; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.id; });

  var ibm = d3.select("#idIBM").datum();
  console.log(ibm); // Object { id="IBM", value="222"}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

then you can get the selection throw d3

then get the object data binded in selection by datum()

update: i  update the file and tested in firefox chrome and ie10 it works well

Comment: nothing is coming to my screen..haven't you wrote  the full code??

Comment: yah i did that but nothing is coming to my screen

Comment: are there any errors in console panel? i try it in my firefox and generate the html: <ul id="comp">
  <li id="idIBM">IBM</li><li id="idMS">MS</li><li id="idGoogle">Google</li></ul>

Comment: i think you did not understand my question i want to select all nodes od a D3 application.but in this fiddle i can not select any thing

Comment: i run your code in chrome and saw that name of three companies are coming but when i go for a selection how it works???i.e i am trying to say that if i click on IBM  the name of IBM should be displayed on console and if on MS it should be in the console and so on and also if i select 3 companies together  their name should be on console..

Comment: see the picture i want this type of functionality when i will select these 3 companies i will see their values in the console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUFg8/2/ i add an event listener and updated the code. when you click on the li, the console will print the id for id.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUFg8/2/ i add an event listener and updated the code. when you click on the li, the console will print the id for it. when you click the displayInfo button, the function will loop through the ul to filter the li in the array, i can't get the coorespond lis as you showed in the picture, maybe you can add an <input type="checkbox"/> in the li and check it in displayInfo

Comment: thanks for your answer it is working but i what i want to say that i want to select item on mouse drag and then want their values in console.you see my screen shot i have selected three companies and that is the way i want their values to the console.not by clicking one by one...

Comment: since i am new to javascript event. i only use click when i study... so i am sorry that i no idea about drag. Good Luck :)